# Login the user when he confirms the email address

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-4.5

Using  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity i have almost all I need to manage the users problems, but I ( a vb.net beginner) can't  update this code to automatically sign in the user when he confirm the email address.

I think I need a method to get ApplicationUser just  based on UsedId

This is the code I try to change:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim code As String = IdentityHelper.GetCodeFromRequest(Request)
    Dim userId As String = IdentityHelper.GetUserIdFromRequest(Request)
    If code IsNot Nothing AndAlso userId IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim result = manager.ConfirmEmail(userId, code)
        If result.Succeeded Then
       '>>>>>>>>login the user  
            successPanel.Visible = True
            Return
        End If
    End If
    successPanel.Visible = False
    errorPanel.Visible = True      
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this question so tricky or my logic is wrong  because nobody is suggesting an idea.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else have this issue, this is the code i used

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim code As String = IdentityHelper.GetCodeFromRequest(Request)
    Dim userId As String = IdentityHelper.GetUserIdFromRequest(Request)
    If code IsNot Nothing AndAlso userId IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim result = manager.ConfirmEmail(userId, code)
        If result.Succeeded Then
            Try

                Dim task = New UserStore(Of Sue.ApplicationUser)(Context.GetOwinContext().[Get](Of ApplicationDbContext)()).FindByIdAsync(userId)
                Dim user = task.Result()

                Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

                signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)

                Context.Response.Redirect("/Account/UserData", False)

            Catch ex As Exception
                successPanel.Visible = False
                errorPanel.Visible = True
                Return
            End Try
        End If
    End If
    successPanel.Visible = False
    errorPanel.Visible = True
End Sub
```